# Why is opendmarc SPF failing this arriving message?

Tags: postfix, spf, dkim, dmarc, opendmarc

Why is this incoming message failing?

```
postfix/smtpd[4776]: connect from mail-mw2nam10on2073.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.94.73]
 postfix/smtpd[4776]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-mw2nam10on2073.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.94.73]: TLSv1.2 with cipher <snip>4 (256/256 bits)
 postfix/smtpd[4776]: 631A5453D55: client=mail-mw2nam10on2073.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.94.73]
 postfix/cleanup[4781]: 631A5453D55: message-id=<414<snip>MDC019E7.cnb.Corp.net>
 opendkim[849]: 631A5453D55: mail-mw2nam10on2073.outbound.protection.outlook.com [40.107.94.73] not internal
 opendkim[849]: 631A5453D55: not authenticated
 opendkim[849]: 631A5453D55: DKIM verification successful
 opendmarc[840]: 631A5453D55 ignoring Authentication-Results at 1 from ip-<snip>.ec2.internal
 opendmarc[840]: 631A5453D55: SPF(mailfrom): some.user@cnb.com fail
 opendmarc[840]: 631A5453D55: cnb.com fail
 postfix/cleanup[4781]: 631A5453D55: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from mail-mw2nam10on2073.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.94.73]: 5.7.1 rejected by DMARC policy for cnb.com; from=<some.user@cnb.com> to=<me@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<NAM10-MW2-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
 postfix/smtpd[4776]: disconnect from mail-mw2nam10on2073.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.94.73]
```

It appears that cnb.com's DNS has the correct MS record (spf.protection.outlook.com) mentioned by MS here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/set-up-spf-in-office-365-to-help-prevent-spoofing?view=o365-worldwide

```
 # dig cnb.com txt|grep spf                                                                                                                              
     cnb.com.                290     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:cnb.com._nspf.vali.email include:%{i}._ip.%{h}._ehlo.%{d}._spf.vali.email ~all"
```

They are coming from an IP in the 40.107.0.0/16 network here:
https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf:spf.protection.outlook.com&newAppVersion=1

Have they done something wrong in their SPF config or is it something on my end?

Comment: Does pass for me, so unless it happened again, its probably safe to assume the record you looked at is not the same that was fetched when the mail was received.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the DNS query do not reach the NS server from some part of the world with nearly 8% failures, it could be related to traffic of firewall rules, as this query shows:

https://atlas.ripe.net/measurements/30167421/#probes